# nav disappearing components using react hooks and react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I was trying to find solution for `NavLink` to disappear while previous menu is clicked.
I tried to get `document.location.pathname` to recieve query value of the current page, so I could use `switch` to compare and then render appropriate Navbar. It obviously worked, but only if I'd hit refresh button every time after I hit one of my `Navlink`. I tried to use hooks, but can't find the solution.

Here is my code:

````
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


    const [isMount, setIsMount] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
       
    });


    function handleClick() {
        setIsMount(props.utm);
    }
    
    
    switch (props.utm) {
        case '/account':
            return (
                <div className="header-nav">
                    <nav className="navBar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><NavLink exact to="home" className="homebutton"> / </NavLink></li>
                            <li onClick={handleClick}><NavLink to="account"> Account /</NavLink></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            );  
        case '/return':
            return (
                <div className="header-nav">
                    <nav className="navBar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><NavLink exact to="home" className="homebutton"> / </NavLink></li>
                            <li><NavLink to="account"> Account /</NavLink></li>
                            <li onClick={handleClick}><NavLink to="return" > Return/Exchange /</NavLink></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            );
        default:
            break;
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the React router package.

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

function Example() {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location.pathname)
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    //In here u can try to check the path and load the component u want
  },[])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change something with dependecies eg. pathName, you can use useEffect. Let me give example :

```
useEffect(()=>{

 ...// something will hapend if pathName change

}, [pathName])
```

And if you want to reference html in useEffect, I suggest you to use useRef()